# Swagger: Use an specific value in the response object

Tags: swagger

I'm creating API docs with swagger and I can't find the way to represent an specific value in a response.

For example when there is a 404 error in the API, the response is like this:

```
{
    "code": 404,
    "result": "payment.notfound"
}
```

The value will always be 404, how can this be expressed in swagger.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 4):

You can like this:

```
/paths:
  /foo:
    /get:
      parameters: []
      responses:
        200:
          description: it worked
        404:
          description: "it didn't work"
          schema:
            type: object
            properties:
              code:
                type: integer
                format: int32
              result:
                type: string
```

If you *really* want to say that `result` can only, ever be the string `payment.notfound`, you can simply set an enum:

```
result:
  type: string
  enum:
    - "payment.notfound"
```

which means, "it's a string but can only be this value, ever".